# R web scraping output "character (empty)"

Tags: r, rvest

I am new to R.

I need help assigning web scraping data to "salary". Somehow, my variable "salary" is showing character (empty) in my environment. I have used SelectorGadget to  find the html nodes.

Would really appreciate it if someone can explain it to me. Thanks!

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

nba_player_salaries <- read_html("https://hoopshype.com/salaries/players/2018-2019/")

salary <- nba_player_salaries %>%
  html_nodes("tbody .hh-salaries-sorted") %>%
  html_text2()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly extract the table from the page :

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

url <- 'https://hoopshype.com/salaries/players/2018-2019/'

url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_table() %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  setNames(.[1, ]) %>% #Since column names are in 1st row
  slice(-1) %>%        #Remove 1st row
  select(-1)           #Remove 1st column

#   Player            `2018/19`   `2018/19(*)`
#   <chr>             <chr>       <chr>       
# 1 Stephen Curry     $37,457,154 $38,320,489 
# 2 Russell Westbrook $35,665,000 $36,487,029 
# 3 Chris Paul        $35,654,150 $36,475,929 
# 4 LeBron James      $35,654,150 $36,475,929 
# 5 Kyle Lowry        $32,700,000 $33,453,690 
# 6 Blake Griffin     $31,873,932 $32,608,582 
# 7 Gordon Hayward    $31,214,295 $31,933,741 
# 8 James Harden      $30,570,000 $31,274,596 
# 9 Paul George       $30,560,700 $31,265,082 
#10 Mike Conley       $30,521,115 $31,224,584 
# … with 566 more rows
```